# In the nutshell, how do I do HTTPS with Indy?

Tags: delphi, ssl, https, indy, indy10

**Actually, my question doesn't have an answer there.**

I keep getting "EOF was observed" with solution (v23) of that answer.
Only `sslvSSLv2` gives a change "error:00000006:lib(0):func(0):EVP lib". Defective DLLs?

---

According to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Securing_Indy_Network_Connections) it's pretty simple - have a DLLs and then just assign `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` instance to `IOHandler` property and switch protocol to `https`. But doing so, I've immediately faced an SSL error with message "Error connecting with SSL. EOF was observed that violates the protocol". Curiously enough, I have `TIdLogDebug` there as well, but I don't see any protocol dump with spurious EOF.

**What should I do to enable HTTPS?**

---

FWIW, I have `TIdHTTP` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` in all-default state (except linked `TIdLogDebug` and `TIdCookieManager`)

```
  object IdHTTP: TIdHTTP
    Intercept = IdLogDebug
    IOHandler = IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
    AllowCookies = True
    ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication = False
    ProxyParams.ProxyPort = 0
    Request.ContentLength = -1
    Request.ContentRangeEnd = -1
    Request.ContentRangeStart = -1
    Request.ContentRangeInstanceLength = -1
    Request.Accept = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
    Request.BasicAuthentication = False
    Request.UserAgent = 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)'
    Request.Ranges.Units = 'bytes'
    Request.Ranges = <>
    HTTPOptions = [hoForceEncodeParams]
    CookieManager = IdCookieManager
    Left = 200
    Top = 56
  end
  object IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
    Intercept = IdLogDebug
    MaxLineAction = maException
    Port = 0
    DefaultPort = 0
    SSLOptions.Mode = sslmUnassigned
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
    Left = 208
    Top = 128
  end
```

---

FWIW again, I'm using XE7 with stock Indy 10.6.1.5182

Comment: Check out the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987485/eidosslconnecterror-error-connecting-with-ssl-eof-was-observed.

Comment: **Something should be done with single-handed closing.**

Comment: @FreeConsulting:  Particularly as there seems to be no obvious equivalent of voting to re-open.  Anyway I've flagged it.

Comment: @Martyn, anyone with a gold badge in one of the tagged topics can close a question as a duplicate with a single vote, commonly referred to as the *[dupehammer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dupehammer)*. Anyone *else* with a gold badge in those topics may re-open the question with a single vote. It's the primary privilege of earning gold badges.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone. Looks like I found a way around this nasty error by using other OpenSSL DLLs. Since I'm in no way an SSL expert, I have no explanation what was wrong and I don't know if I should post my notes as an answer...