# SHA 256 With Indy

Tags: indy, delphi

I am trying to use the SHA-256 encryption function, but with no success.

I need to get a hash of a string and a file.
I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin, and Indy for Hash.

My code:

```
uses System.Classes, IdHashSha, System.SysUtils;

function GetHashF(_filename: string): string;
  var
   sha: TIdHashSHA256;
   fs: TFileStream;
  begin
   if TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
    begin
     sha:= TIdHashSHA256.Create;
     try
      fs:= TFileStream.Create(_filename, fmOpenRead);
      try
       Result:= sha.HashStreamAsHex(fs);
      finally
       sha.Free;
      end;
     finally
      fs.Free;
     end;
    end;

 function GetHashS(_string: string): string;
  var
   sha: TIdHashSHA256;
  begin
   if TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
    begin
     sha:= TIdHashSHA256.Create;
     try
      Result:= sha.HashStringAsHex(_string);
     finally
      sha.Free;
     end;
    end;
  end;
```

But whenever I do this, it returns a clean string ("") for both function.
I used the breakpoint to check if it is passing from `IsAvaible`, and it is not.
  What is going on?

Comment: You coded that way, even implementation is non available for you the execution continues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this time, Indy only implements a few hashing algorithms *natively*, but that does not include SHA-256 (I have [created a ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/169) for that feature).

For algorithms not implemented natively, Indy allows you to hook in an external hashing implementation of your choosing to provide the actual hash functionality.  You are seeing `IsAvailable` return false because you have not done that hookup yet.

You can use any hash implementation you want, as long as you assign appropriate wrapper functions to the following callbacks in the `IdFIPS` unit:

```
IsHashingIntfAvail
UpdateHashInst
FinalHashInst
```

And for SHA-256 specifically, also:

```
GetSHA256HashInst
IsSHA256HashIntfAvail
```

By default, Indy can use OpenSSL as a hashing library:

- add the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to your `uses` clause
- call `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load()` at runtime
- deploy the OpenSSL binaries with your app executable.

`IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` hooks up relevant OpenSSL functions for the `IdFIPS` callbacks.

Comment: Need a specific version of OpenSSL binaries? Thanks.

Comment: @strykerbits, any 0.9.8l+ [**should**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40120183/205376) work.