# Base64 Hash from PDF file different between C# and Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, hash, base64, sha256

I'm trying to generate a hash from a PDF. This hash should be SHA256 and Base64.
I'm using a simple PDF with one line with the content: Hello World.

With the C# code below I've got the result:
**Gv5AR2YOxUVOjx+QFakM56Wj7CSqeZWiaVqczra/iBk=**

```
string digest;
using (SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed())
{
    byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(pdf);
    digest = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

Then, using Delphi, with the code below, I've got this:
**wPUoG1guk2hQ5TxS5lUmaMLk83E=**

```
// uses IdCoderMIME, IdHashSHA, IdGlobal;

var
  oHash: TIdHashSHA1;
  oFileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  oHash := TIdHashSHA1.Create;
  oFileStream := TFileStream.Create(edtPDFPath.Text, fmOpenRead);
  try
    result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(oHash.HashStream(oFileStream, 0, oFileStream.Size));
  finally
    Freeandnil(oFileStream);
    oHash.Free
  end;
```

I need to hash this file with Delphi but I don't know if my result is right or not.

Someone knows another way to get as a result a SHA256 Base64 hash?

Comment: SHA1 is not SHA256.  `TIdHashSHA1` implements SHA1.  `SHA256Managed` implements SHA256.  They are not the same.  Note that SHA1 has been deprecated for a decade and a half.

Comment: Related : [SHA 256 With Indy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43173249/327083)

Answer (score 1):

You can get same result as C# with following code

```
// uses System.Hash, System.NetEncoding;
Result := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(oFileStream, THashSHA2.TSHA2Version.SHA256));
```

Comment: Thank you @Eugenek . Now I am trying to decrypt the hashed String and save it to a PDF file again, but I can't find a way to do this. I've tried something like bellow:
`var
  stream: TBytesStream;
begin
  stream := TBytesStream.Create(TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(base64HashString));
  try
    stream.SaveToFile(Filename);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
`
But the generated file is corrupted, with invalid characters.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, you cannot recover PDF file from its hash, it is one way operation.